# How to port app from Borland Pascal to FreePascal and Unicode terminal

Tags: freepascal

I am trying to port my first app I ever wrote from old Borland Pascal to FreePascal and run it in Linux unicode shell.

Unfortunately, the app uses CRT unit and writes non-standard ASCII graphical characters. So I tried to rewrite statements like these:

```
gotoxy(2,3); write(#204);
writeln('3. Intro');
```

to these:

```
gotoxy(2,3); write('╠');
write('3. Intro', #10);
```

Two notes:

- I use unicode characters directly in code because I did not find out how to write unicode characters via their code.
- I used `write` procedure instead of `writeln` to make sure that unix line endings will be produced.

But after replacing all non-standard ASCII characters and getting rid of all `writeln` statements, it became even worse.

Before changes:

[image: screen before changes]

After changes:

[image: screen after changes]

Why it ends up like this? What I can do better?

---

After some time here is an update what I found out.

**1) I cannot port it**

As user @dmsc rightly pointed out, CRT does not support UTF-8. His suggested hack that did not work for me.

**2) When you can't port it, emulate environment.**

The graphical characters I needed were part of [CP-437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). There is a program called [luit](http://invisible-island.net/luit/) that is made for converting application output from the locale's encoding into UTF-8. Unfortunately this does not work for me. It simple erased the characters:

```
# Via iconv, everything is OK:
$ printf "top right corner in CP437: \xbf \n" | iconv -f CP437 -t UTF-8
top right corner in CP437: ┐
# But not via luit, that simply omit the character:
$ luit -gr g2 -g2 'CP 437' printf "top right corner in CP437: \xbf \n"
top right corner in CP437:
```

So my solution is to run gnome-terminal, add and set Hebrew (IBM862) encoding ([tutorial here](http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/IBMgraphics#gnome-terminal)) and enjoy your app!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CRT unit does not currently works with UTF-8, as it assumes that each character on the screen is exactly one byte, see http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html-3.0.0/rtl/crt/index.html

But, simple applications can be made to work by "tricking" GotoXY to always do a full cursor positioning, by doing:

```
GotoXY(1,1);
GotoXY(x, y);
```

To replace all the strings in your source file, you can use recode, in a terminal type:

```
recode cp437..u8 < original.pas > fixed.pas
```

Then, you need to replace all the numeric characters (like your #204 example) with the equivalent UTF-8, you can use:

```
echo -e '\xCC' | recode cp437/..u8
```

The 'CC' is hexadecimal for 204, and as a result the character '╠' will be printed.

Comment: I replaced all GotoXY with procedure uGotoXY that resets position of cursor as you suggest. I also removed all write statements that writes more than one character. It helped, but not completely. What exactly means "simple applications"? (And thanks for your answer, it is embarrassing that I did not read the documentation :(()

Comment: Because CRT does not support UTF-8, the answer is the port cannot be done. So I can accept this answer as a solution.